# CS50P meal problem: "timed out while waiting for program to exit"

Tags: python, timeout

I am trying to solve the meal problem in Harvard CS50. When i run the code it executes successfully, but when I submit it, it says time out. Below is my code. Please guide me in this situation.

```
def main():
    time = input("what time is it?")
    a = convert(time)
    print(a)
    if  7<=a and a<=8:
        print("breakfast time")
    elif 12<=a and a<=13:
        print("Lunch time")
    elif 18<=a and a<=19:
        print("dinner time")
    else:
        return







def convert (time):
    hours, minutes = time.split(":")
    hours = int(hours)
    minutes = int (minutes)
    if minutes > 60:
        print("minutes can't be greater than 60")
        return
    else:
        float_minutes = minutes/60
        converted_time = hours + float_minutes
    return converted_time


main()
```

When i submit this code it must be executed successfully as per my expectation, but i get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most likely scenario is that the input of the test case is `12:00` instead of `12:00\n`, causing the `input()` function to block the entire program execution.

Comment: This is wrong: try `echo -n 12 | python -c 'print(input())'`. There is no newline - should this hang forever?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't contain any loops or recursive function calls, so the only place where it can possibly be hanging is on the `input()` call. This function will sit there and wait for input from stdin (that is, wait for the user to type something and press enter). If there is no input, then the program never exits.

Did the assignment say that the input will come from stdin? If so, there might be a problem with the test framework, so ask the teacher.

The other possibility is that the test framework sends the input as an argument to the script. If so, then you can read it like this:

```
import sys

# (...)

time = sys.argv[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the line mentioned by the teacher. The added line is given below and it solved the problem, but i don't understand how did it solve the issue. please elaborate on that line.
The added line is
'if **name** == "**main**":
main()'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).